# I am pausing windows update for 7 days, but I still have it running

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-update

Please, tell me anyone how this can be possible, I am both pausing windows update and having it running.

1. Windows update settings

[image]

2. Pausing windows updates

[image]

3. Restart computer
4. Open task manager

[image]

Comment: The service has to run anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Windows Update is always running and is pretty hard to disable.

Even when updates are paused, it will still look for urgent updates
(usually about security) that will be installed in spite of your settings.

This is normal, and doesn't mean that Windows Update will not respect
your demand to not install normal (non-urgent) updates up until the
displayed date.